# Two matlab2tikz figures side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tex-core, matlab2tikz, sidebyside

I want to have two figures generated with matlab2tikz side by side.

I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{grffile}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, calrsfs, wasysym, verbatim, bbm, color, graphics, geometry}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amscd, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{calc}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{normal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]  
\centering 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
   \input{texFigures/fig1}
    \caption{No interaction} \label{fig:M1}  
  \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
  \input{texFigures/fig2}
\caption{Interaction} \label{fig:M2}  
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Interaction figures}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

but I dont have any output. No error Log for this problem too, just no visual output. The figures exist as .tex files generated via

```
savefig('figXY.fig')

cleanfigure;
matlab2tikz('figXY.tex');
```

The error / warning logs i get are caption package warnings (hypcap = true) ignored and tons of overfull and underfull warnings.

Comment: Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and provide code that can be tested. Also "don't have any output" isn't a usable statement. What does the log says? Do you have an error message?

Comment: A resource for syntax of tex figures (fig.tex) would be enough

Comment: Assuming that fig1 and fig2 exist as files, this syntax is correct, so you won't get much help if you don't explain what the problem is.

Comment: @Miyase i have edited the post and included all packages im using to rule known conflicts out, which i dont know about.

Comment: Thanks. Your code is missing its `\documentclass` macro. Not only is it necessary for compilation, but knowing which class you're using can be important.

Comment: This code doesn't compile here with TeX Live 2022: 1) `subfig` is an *extremely* obsolete package, replacing it with `subcaption` works fine, 2) `amsthm` conflicts with something else (Command `\theoremstyle` already defined), removing it works fine. After those two corrections, your code compiles with figures included. Are you sure the TeX code inside your fig files is valid?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes i think the tex code is valid because \input{texfigures/fig1} in a center environment shows the image.

Comment: Then start with replacing `subfig` with `subcaption`.

Comment: Also, I see that you're loading `graphics`, which is already loaded automatically by `graphicx`, you're loading `color` twice but never `xcolor`, etc. It might be worth some time to clean up your preamble.

Comment: yep i cleaned it up a little now and included subcaption. I get a visual output but the figures are overlapping, no matter how i choose the subfigure linewidth and they are too big. I cant find any info about scaling .tex figures though

Comment: The width parameter given to subfigure is only the width given to the space for the figure, but is unrelated to the width of the figure itself. If you could use the `\includegraphics` command, the figure's width can be given as an option to it.

Comment: As `help matlab2tikz` will tell you, you can set the width with `matlab2tikz('width',CHAR)`, e.g. `matlab2tikz('width','7cm')` or `matlab2tikz('width','\textwidth')`.